# URL_TITLE() CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a college table in my database which has 3 columns:

```
college_id   college_name      college_description 
----------   -------------     -------------------
1            U.K. College      Some Description
2            U.S. College      Another Description
```

Now I have to display anchor links on a page each directing me to respective college's description page. One solution is to include college_id in anchor link like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/colleges/u.k. college/1
```

so that when user clicks on this link, I use the id from the url and get the college description from the database against the id. Apparently I dont want URLS to look like this. I don't want id to be included in url and just the college name. So I used url_title() function in Codeigniter and and achieved what I was looking for. Hence the url turned into this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/colleges/uk-college
```

I liked the fact that url_title removed the periods from within the college name but I am trying to figure out how could I use the college name now to fetch the respective description from database. Can I somehow keep the urls without periods(dots) and still fetch the description from database?

Thanks!

Comment: if you take a look at the codeigniter tutorial it will give you a solution - but basically you use url_title() to create a "slug". the slug is what is shown in the url, AND you use the slug for searching to find your college. which also mean you use the slug for your links. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store the slugs (the title created by `url_title()`) in the database. Create a new column in your table called `slug`, and when you create a new entry use `url_title()` to create the slug and insert it in the `slug` column. Then you can search by slug to retrieve the correct college.